# Postgresql, "Gem::LoadError: pg is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rake, bundler

I am running on a Windows.

On my Project, I did a Bundle Install with no errors.  Then I try to do rake db:create, it says 
[image]

[image]

I did a gem install pg, which worked but I still get this error.  Judging by the error, I think it is saying that it doesn't recognize PostgreSQL installed on my computer but I do have it installed.  I have 9.6 installed:
[image]

I also created an Environment Path but to no result.
What am I missing here?

Comment: Have you added `pg` to your Gemfile and then run `bundle install`?

Comment: yup, it's in there, something like this?: gem 'pg', :platforms => :ruby

Comment: And what happened when you run `bundle install`? It installed correctly? Because `pg` gem has native extensions and sometimes they don't compile correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Did you add the gem to your gemfile? "bundle add pg" in your terminal followed by 'bundle install'. This should solve your problem.